# Scala, Type could not find implicit value for parameter n

Tags: scala

```
import Numeric._
import grizzled.math.stats._

val l = List[Double](123.0, 133.0, 155.0, 166.0, 177.0)
println(median(l))
```

Above you see an example which describes the usage of the package `grizzled.math.stats` at [scala grizzled doc](http://software.clapper.org/grizzled-scala/api/#grizzled.math.stats%24). I am not able to reproduce this simple example.

I always get following errors:

- could not find implicit value for parameter n: Numeric[Array[Double]]
- not enough arguments for method median: (implicit n: Numeric[Array[Double]])Double. Unspecified value parameter n.

Any suggestion to resolve this compilation error is welcome.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`median` expects a var-arg argument. You could expand the list with `_*` syntax, like this:

```
import Numeric._
import grizzled.math.stats._

val l = List[Double](123.0, 133.0, 155.0, 166.0, 177.0)
println(median(l: _*))
```

This compiles and outputs 155.0.